# How to connect a solenoid to the Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit LE

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, solenoid, adafruit

How would I connect the to the [Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2995) to this [Mini Push-Pull Solenoid - 5V](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2776) so that I can via bluetooth send over instructions to the microcontroller to control the solenoid?

Comment: google "mosfet as a switch arduino" for plenty of amauture-targeted  advice.

Comment: Note that both of the Adafruit pages that you link to actually have additional links with application examples. They should provide more than enough to get you started.